# Видимость обьекта в разных классах

Tags: java

```
class one {
    Server_Form okno = new Server_Form();
    okno.setVisible(true);   
}

class two {
    // Как организовать доступ обьекта "okno" из класса one в этом классе?
    // Чтобы я мог сделать следующее: okno.command_serv(); 
}
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Почему вы не можете просто ссылку на okno передать в two?

Comment: А как передать эту ссылку? Я новичок, извините.

Answer (score 2):

```
class One {
    private Two two;

    public void test() {
        ServerForm okno = new ServerForm(two);
        okno.setVisible(true);
        okno.commandServ();
    }

}

class Two {
    public void doSometing(){ }
}

class ServerForm ...... {
    private final Two two;

    public ServerForm(Two two) {
        this.two = two;
    }

    // .. setVisible, etc

    public void commandServ() {
        two.doSomething();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class one
{
    private JFrame wnd = null ;

    public void someMethod()
    {
        if (null == wnd)
        {
            wnd = new JFrame();
        }

        wnd.setVisible(true);
    }
    public JFrame getWnd ()
    {
        return wnd ;
    }

    public void setWnd ( JFrame wnd )
    {
        this.wnd = wnd ;
    }
}

class two
{
    public void someMethod (one ref)
    {
        ref.getWnd ().setVisible ( false );
    }
}
```

бесплатные советы:
1) никогда не используйте транслит в коде программ, за это вы попадете в ад для кодеров!
2) никогда не называйте классы с маленькой буквы, за это вы попадате в ад для кодеров!